# fuzzyCLIPS examples

Tags: fuzzy, clips

I am learning how to use the version of fuzzyCLIPS from NRC. I would
appreciate if someone could point out some ftp/web sites with examples and
code using fuzzyCLIPS. I find the manual difficult to learn from

Answer (score 1):

Try a search for FuzzyJess. As the syntax for CLIPS and Jess are similar you might find some FuzzyJess examples that can be adapted to FuzzyCLIPS.